# neo4j Cypher query- update changed fields only

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, neo4j

This is a really simple question and I really don't understand how to do this. I have a form where a user can update information, that information needs to be updated in the database. I keep getting the exception invalid data access resource usage and I know something is wrong with my query. I am using neo4j database. Can anyone help update the fields of an object in the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My form:

```
<form:form action="dogEdited" method="get">
    <label for="usr">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${updateDog.getName()}" name="name"><br>
    <label for="usr">Weight (lb):</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${updateDog.getWeight()}" name="weight"><br>
    <label for="usr">Heartbeat (b/min):</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${updateDog.getHeartbeat()}" name="heartbeat"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${updateDog.getId()}"/>
    <div style="text-align: center; display: block;"><input type="submit" class="btn-success" value="Enter" /></div>
</form:form>
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dogEdited", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editDog(@RequestParam("id") Long id, @ModelAttribute CreateDogs updatedDog,ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse response){
        repo.updateByID(updatedDog);

        return "displayInfo";
    }
```

My query in database (where the problem occurs):

```
@Query(value="start n=node({dog}.getId()) set n.weight={dog}.getWeight();")
    void updateByID(@Param("dog") CreateDogs dog);
```

What I want to do is update all fields or any changed fields with the object passed in as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call methods in cypher as Cypher doesn't know anything about POJOs or Java objects.

e.g. `{dog}.getId()`

I'd recommend to just pass two parameters for `id` and `weight` or a map with `{id:3345, weight:24}`.

then you can do:

```
match (n) where id(n) = {dog}.id set n.weight={dog}.weight
```